# ERROR: Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode

Tags: errors, font-encodings, input-encodings

Why do I get an "ERROR: Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode." for the following code?

```
\[c=439 450\times10^6\frac{\mathrm{millimètre}}{\mathrm{seconde}}\]
```

I am guessing `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is having problems with the accented "è" in "millimètre."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works fine when you use `\text` instead of `\mathrm`. `\text` is part of `amsmath`, which is loaded by `mathtools` …

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[c=439 450\times10^6\frac{\text{millimètre}}{\text{seconde}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

`\mathrm` won’t create real text, it only changes the *math* alphabet from italics to recto. But in the math alphabet there are no accent characters like `è` …

Comment: By the way … [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) provides a powerful mechanism for numbers, values and units …

Comment: By the way 2 … The space in `439 450`will be removed by TeX since it has it’s own spacing rules in mathmode. You may use `439\,450` to insert a small space. (Shouldn’t it be `43\,9450`??)